# how to use Tcl language to control simulation

Tags: tcl

I want to use tcl to control simulation iteration.
In each iteration, I get some random value, and save the results

```
set set_of_double_values{0}
foreach y_val $set_of_double_values {
set_parameter Snr $y_val ;

set numsim 2;
set_value/$env(sim_name)/numsim $numsim;
for {set i 0} {$i < $numsim} {incr i 1} {
some random value
}
run_iteration;
}
run_iteration
```

using this code, I always run the inner part many times, and I can not save the right results...

Comment: The code as you have given it will error on the very first line with "can't read "set_of_double_values{0}": no such variable." Assuming you actually set it to be a list with one value you would then loop over the foreach body one time as it only has one value. You then have a set_parameter procedure you have not provided a definition for and other bits that don't look like tcl at all (set_value/$env(sim_name)/numsim  -- this would be a procedure named "set_value/xxxx/numsim" where xxx is whatever you have in the sim_name environment variable. I suggest you post a _working_ snippet.

Comment: @patthoyts That `set_value/...` stuff is prevalent in one of the simulators built on top of Tcl; I've seen it before. (Can't remember _which_ simulator though, as there's loads of different ones.)

Comment: It is base on concentric system studio. There are some commends that from concentric system studio. And the simulation control file (.scf) is writing in TCL.